# The difference between zero conditional and first conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

Here I have an explanation on the difference between zero conditional and second conditional:

[image]

I can't grasp the difference between to examples above:

This one is given as the example of zero conditional:

> "You should see a doctor if a headache doesn't go away."

And this one is given as an example of first conditional:

> "If your eyes hurt, you should check whether you need glasses."

The explanation says that zero conditional sentences describe situations that are generally or always true, and the second conditional sentences describe future possible situations. But it looks to me that each one of those two sentences matches both categories.

The book is "Perspectives", level 2.

Comment: You have written "second conditional" in the title. You must also cite the source, what is the name of the text book. You seem to have skipped **other modals or an imperative can replace "will"** The word "should" is a modal.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "You have written "second conditional" in the title" - Thanks. I'll edit the title. "You must also cite the source" - Why? How would that help?

Comment: "You should see a doctor if a headache doesn't go away" is a universally true statement, while "If your eyes hurt, you should check whether you need glasses" maybe only applies in a particular situation or for a particular person (it may be specific "you"=the person being talked to, not generic "you"). I agree the difference is not very clear and they're not great examples. But anyone can post English lessons online and the quality is often not great.

Comment: Sources are important because we can tell you if they are reliable or not, and when quoting (just a reminder images cannot be searched) someone or something it must be attributed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I see. Well, this is "Perspectives-2" book. I will add the image of the book to the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Okay. Just took it down. But how would people then know which "Perspectives" textbook exactly it is?

Comment: Sorry to continue with the nagging, but images with text are inaccessible to people using screen readers, so are not allowed, unless the whole text in them is typed out either in the image description code where it says, "enter image description here", or in the body of the question itself. Either way, it's best to type out only the parts you need to refer to, format it as a quote, and then give attribution to the source book.

Comment: @gotube - "Either way, it's best to type out only the parts you need to refer to, format it as a quote" - But that's exactly what I did! My question was not about the image of the text, but about the image of the textbook's front cover. I don't understand why that image cannot be posted here and only the textbook's title and the level must be specified instead. What if there are two different textbooks, by two different publishers, yet sharing the same title?

Comment: @brilliant Great. If you've quoted the only parts you need from the book, then you can remove the image of the text, and just give enough information to make it unambiguous which book you're referring to. Someone using a screen reader won't know which book you mean from the image, and they don't have access to all the text in the other image, nor is that text searchable. Quoting the relevant parts and giving the title, level and publisher is certainly enough information, and is fully accessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: @gotube - "Quoting the relevant parts and giving the title, level and publisher is certainly enough information" - But what if there is another textbook with the same title?

Comment: @brilliant By the same publisher? If you mean a different edition, then include the edition number as well.

Comment: @gotube - "By the same publisher?" - No. By two different publishers.

Comment: Then including the publisher's name is enough to uniquely identify the book

Comment: @gotube - Ah, I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to what it says in the image you posted:

- Zero conditional sentences are situations that are *generally true*.
- First conditional sentences describe *possible future situations*.

As is often the case, **context matters**.

Take the example:

> "If your eyes hurt, you should check whether you need glasses."

If you saw this on a billboard, or someone randomly said it to you without knowing anything about your ocular health, then it would be a piece of general advice and an example of zero conditional. It meets the criteria - "you should" is an imperative with a modal. 'You' is the *generic you*', a colloquial substitute for 'one', so this is a piece of general advice that could apply to anybody.

However, if someone has just told you that their eyes hurt and you say this to them then it would be *first conditional*. You're not telling them a general piece of advice - you're giving them specific advice about what should happen in immediate future. 'You' actually means *you*.